# Is Ashapuri Maa mentioned in any scripture?

Tags: scripture, devi, goddess, shakti

We can see temples of Ashapuri Maa at piplav and kutch (mata no madh)

As name suggest Ashapuri Maa fullfills desires of person.

[Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashapura_Mata) says Ashapuri Maa is expansion of Shakambhari devi.

Is there any reference to Ashapuri Maa in the scriptures?

Comment: The Ashapuri mentioned in scriptures is different from the Ashapura at Madh or Nadol. The name Ashapura was given by Rao Lakhan to Shakambhari because she fulfilled his wish to establish rule over Nadol.  While the Ashapuri mentioned in scriptures is actually called Ashapuri herself n she is a different form of devi. Thus the term Ashapura is a misnomer, & with passing day the real form was forgotten & just the name Ashapura got into masses.

Comment: @Chamundadas does the goddess mentioned in scripture has 7 pairs of eye?

Comment: Nope, only the name 'Ashapuri' appears in Skanda Puran. No referances are made to eyes. The 7 pairs that you see in her Vigraha are those which are 'visible'. As, I said she is Shakambhari thus she has 100 eyes, the remaining are present in sukshma roop thus not seen to naked eyes. Also if scriptures had to mention Ashapura they would call her by name Shakambhari. I will answer this question as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

```
Is there any reference to Ashapuri Maa in the scriptures?
```

Nope, Ashapura (Shakambhari devi) is not present in Shastras. Even if the temple website claims so, it can be purely denied & debated based on certain facts. The name Ashapuri appears thrice in Skanda purana. But all of them are not the one we are talking about.

Section 2 - Dharmāraṇya-khaṇḍa
Chapter 9 - Different Spiritual Lineages and Their Goddesses

> 108-111. The Gotra-mothers are the following: Śrīmātṛ, Tāraṇīdevī, **Āśāpurī**, Gotrapā, Icchārtināśinī, Pippalī, Vikāravaśā, Jaganmātā, Mahāmātā, Siddhā, Bhaṭṭārikā, Kadaṃbā, Vikatā, Mīṭhā, Suparṇā, Vasujā, Mataṅgī, Mahādevī, Vāṇī, Mukuṭeśvarī, Bhadrī, Mahāśakti, Saṃhārī, Mahābalā, Cāmuṇḍā the great goddess. They have been installed there for the protection by Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Maheśa and others..

These are the devis of Dharmaranya, which covers Sitapur, Gaya, Mirzapur, & runs till Modhera & Siddhpur ranges in Gujarat. While Ashapura devi is situated in Kutch(Gujarat) which is not a part of Dharmaranya. Also, Modhera & Mata no Madh are **534 kms** apart.
But, there is more strong evidence mentioned in next chapter.

Chapter 22 - Installation of the Deities

> 6-8. They are **Āśāpurī**, Gātrāī, Chatrāī, Jñānajā, Pippalāṃbā, Śāntā, Siddhā, Bhaṭṭārikā, Kadaṃbā, Vikaṭā, Mīṭhā, Suparṇā, Vasujā, Mātaṅgī, Mahādevī, Vārāhī, Mukuṭeśvarī, Bhadrā, Mahāśakti, Śiṃhārā and Mahābalā. These and many others too (are installed). It is difficult to mention all.
> 9-12. The goddesses are of different forms. They take different guises. In the northern side of the holy spot near **Āśāpūrṇā goddess**, Ānandā who gives delight is present in the East.

> 16. About twenty-one kilometres in the southern direction from the holy spot is stationed **Vindhyavāsinī**. She is equipped with weapons. She removes the fright of the devotees. She is endowed with beauty of form.

So, it mentions the Shaktipeeeth Vindhyavasini devi to be just 21 kms frm there. Which is impossible. Because as per map duo are as far as 1739 kms.

Uttarardha of Kashi Khand,
Chapter 67 - In Praise of Ratneśvara

> 171.This is Goddess **Āśāpurī** on the splendid **banks of Mandākinī**. She was eulogized by Tripurāri (Śiva) when he was desirous of conquering Tripura.

Thus, we see Kashi & Kutch are spread apart by 1000s of km. Also, Mandakini river gives the ultimate proof, as Mandkini exclusively flows in Uttarakhand. Thus, all possible claim that the Devi is mentioned in Shastras is cancelled out.

**Now another question arises that maybe the devi Ashapuri is Ashapura herself?**
The answer is a big **No**.                   Ashapuri & Ashapura are different devis. As, Ashapuri devi was eulogized by Shiva, whereas **Ashapura** name was given to Shakambhari, by the then ruler of Nadol, Rao Lakhan. (Anecdote below).

This can be understood with an analogy. For example when we take the term Ganesh. Ganesh means the lord of Ganas. Now, Vinayaka is a Ganesh, Nandi too is Ganesh, and but obviously Shiva is Ganesh too. So, we see the same term is used to address different deities but had same characteristic of being Lord of Ganas.                        Same implies with the name Ashapura. The deities are different, although names may mean same.

```
Wikipedia says Ashapuri Maa is expansion of Shakambhari devi
```

She is not expansion of Shakambhari, but is Shakambhari herself as Ashapura.
This can be verified by the fact that at Piplav devi is established in two forms. And those are Shatakshi & Shakambhari.
But, how she got the name Ashapura is another very interesting anecdote (one of my favourite too).

You can read [this article on blog](https://www.missionkuldevi.in/en/2017/11/ashapura-mata-temple-nadol/) to know full itihas.

Thus, as mentioned in Marwari historic work 'Nainsin Ri Khyaat', that Rao Lakhan came from Sambhar after being expelled & he worshipped his Kuldevi who was Shakambhari. But, since she helped him to establish his rule, Rao Lakhan called her, **Ashapura**.

**Now, how Ashapura went to Madh is another story.**

> The most well known and popular version is that about 1500 years ago Karad Vania from Marwar (a term loosely used in olden times for the present – day Rajasthan) was touring this area to sell his wares, and stopped in the spot where the present temple of the goddess stands to spend the nine days of ‘navratri’ as he was a devotee of the Goddess Amba. He did not have any child, so he always prayed to her to give him a child.         While sleeping in the night he saw the deity in his dream who asked him to build a temple on the spot where he stopped.

[Source - Temple website](https://matanamadh.org/madh-history/)

**Fact Check-**
At that time Ashapura was established at only 2 places one in Shambhar, 2nd in Nadol. Now Nadol falls in Marwar & Sambhar in Shekhavati region. Karad Vaniyo was Marwari (resident of Marwar) thus it's evident that he took Shakambhari from Nadol with him, also till then Rao Lakhan coined the name to devi as Ashapura.

Thus, that's how devi went all from Sambhar to Nadol & from there to Mata no Madh.

[image]

She has 14 eyes, which are visible in her Shringar. The rest 86 are present in sukshma roop.

(**PS**- One of my family member comes frm Chauhan clan who have Ashapura of Nadol as tutelery deity & also Nadol is just a few Km drive frm my hometown. Thus all shastric & historic facts r well researched & reliable.)

**कालिकार्पणमस्तु ।**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's references to goddess Āśāpurī in the Skanda Mahā-Purāṇa.

> [Verse 4.2.17.71](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423806.html)
>
> **असावाशापुरी देवी** या स्तुता त्रिपुरारिणा ।
>  त्रिपुरं जेतुकामेन
> मंदाकिन्यास्तटे शुभे ॥ ७१ ॥
>  याद्यापि पूजिता मर्त्यैराशां
> पूरयतेर्थिनाम् ।
>
> > 171. **This is Goddess Āśāpurī on the splendid banks of Mandākinī. She was eulogized by Tripurāri (Śiva) when he was desirous of conquering
> >      Tripura.**
> >
> > - **Even today when she is adored by men, she fulfills the hopes
> >   and ambitions of the suppliants.**

Other references include Skandamahāpurāṇam [Verse 3.2.9.108](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423630.html) and [Verse 3.2.22.6,9](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423643.html).

Comment: So u just went to wisdomlib and searched ashapuri without even a cross-check that whether she is the same godess or not.