# How many avatars of Adi Shakti are mentioned in Skanda Purana?

Tags: goddess, skanda-purana

The Nagara Khanda of Skanda Purana mentiones Katyayani, Kaushiki/Chamunda, Srimata and Kelīshvari are the avatars of Devi Adi Shakti.

> For the destrucion of Mahiṣāsura she descended to the earth as Kātyāyanī. The great form of the goddess extended all over the three worlds.

> When the two Dānavas, Śuṃbha and Niśuṃbha became haughty on account of their strength, she hereself incarnated assuming the form of Cāmuṇḍā.

> When Kālayavana striking terror into the Devas rose up, she was born on the earth in the form of Śrīmātā.

> For the destruction of Andhāsura, Goddess Kelīśvarī was created by Śaṃbhu who occupied her mind and the entire universe was pervaded by her.

In Avantya Khanda of Skanda Purana, Devi incarnated as Harasiddhi to destroy the asuras called Chanda and Prachanda.

Expect this, The other forms of Devi are mentioned in Skanda Purana?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devi Incarnated as [Lalitoma Vishalakshi](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626849.html) during Chakshusha Manvantara.

> 4-8.In the Cākṣuṣa Manvantara, O goddess, when the excessively powerful Daityas proceeded towards the southern quarter on being slain by Viṣṇu, they fought for more than a hundred years in a great battle there with Viṣṇu. O goddess of Devas, they fought with wonderful missiles of various kinds. Knowing that they could not be killed easily, the lotus-eyed Viṣṇu remembered Bhairavī Śakti, the Mahāmāyā of great lustre. On being remembered by Viṣṇu, the all-powerful one, the great goddess came there within a moment with her eyes shining with great delight. At the sight of Viṣṇu, the eyes became large and wide (Viśāla). Hence the goddess stationed there who is the destroyer of Daityas, became (known as) Viśālākṣī. In this Kalpa, O lady of excellent countenance, she is called Lalitomā.

For cure the disease of King Ajapala, Devi Bhairavi manisfeted as [Ajapaleshvari](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626846.html).

> 1-4. Thereafter, O great goddess, a pilgrim should go to the excellent shrine of Ajāpāleśvarī established not very far from Agastya Sthāna to the east. The excellent king Ajāpāla born of the race of Raghu, propitiated the goddess that controls evil diseases. The king took the diseases in the form of goats and made them graze. There he installed the goddess who destroys sins. The goddess was named after him.

She also incarnated as [Kantaka Soshani](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc627105.html) for save the Yajna from Asuras.

> I shall describe the origin thereof, O my beloved. Listen with attentive mind. The following excellent Brāhmaṇas began their Yajña on the southern side of Unnata (Raised Mound). They were: Bhṛgu, Atri, Marīci, Bharadvāja, Kaśyapa, Kaṇva, Manki, Sāvarṇi, Jātūkarṇya, Vatsa, Vasiṣṭha, Pulastya, Pulaha, Kratu, Manu, Yama, Aṅgiras, Viṣṇu, Śātātapa, Parāśara, Śāṇḍilya, Kauśika, Gautama, Gārgya, Dālbhya, Śaunaka, Śākalya, Gālava, Jābāli, Mudgala, Ṛṣyaśṛṅga, Vibhāṇḍaka, Viśvāmitra, Śatānanda, Jahnu and Viśvāvasu.
>
> 7. These and other sages, O splendid lady, built the Yajña-Vāṭa on the excellent banks of Ṛṣitoyā and performed the worship by means of different kinds of sacrifices.
>
> 8-9. The whole atmosphere was rapturous with the notes of flutes and lutes, dances of Devas and Gandharvas, loud chanting of the Vedas, the sweet, fragrant smokes of Yajñas, Homas, Agnihotras and the flavour of the sacrificial ghee. It was given additional glory by the divine sages and excellent Brāhmaṇas belonging to all the Vedic Śākhās (Branches).
>
> 10. On seeing such a place, highly powerful Daityas came from the middle of the ocean for destroying the Yajñas.
> 11. The Daityas of huge bodies, large bellies, dark colour, hanging beards and eyebrows, protruding tips of noses, red eyes, red hairs etc., were adepts in the employment of Māyā (illusory tactics, black magic jugglery etc.)
>
> 12-14. O lady of excellent countenance, all the Daityas entered the place of Yajña. On seeing these people of terrible forms and features, some of the sages fell down. Others entered Patnīśālā and Havirdhāna. The Ṛtviks stood stunned in the centre of the chamber completely tongue-tied.
>
> 15-16. O goddess, when this happened to the noble-souled sages, the Adhvaryu of great splendour and refulgence was courageous enough to perform Agnihotra respectfully. Being a knower of suitable Mantras he kindled the sacrificial fire and performed Homa therein for the sake of destroying the Rākṣasas.
>
> 17. O goddess of Lords, when the Havis was poured the holy fire, goddess Śakti instantly rose up armed with Śakti and trident. The highly resplendent deity held a leathern shield in her hand.
> 18. Those Daityas who had come to destroy the Yajña were killed by her. Then the sages eulogized her by means of different kinds of hymns and prayers.

Other incarnations of Devi- Tara, Siddhambika, Bhaskarā, Yoganandini, the nine Durgas and Bhutamata is mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc366034.html).

In [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423819.html) of Kashi Khanda, Paulomi (Sachi) worshipped Devi's another aspect, Vishvabhuja Gauri.

Devi's another incarnation, Shuleshvari's origin is mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425927.html).

Devi also incarnated as Panchapinda Gauri. Her origin was mentioned in [this chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc502157.html).

For killing Mahishasura's grandsons, Bala and Atibala Devi incarnates as [Balātibaladaityaghni](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626907.html).

Comment: I forgot to say about Ashapuri Mata, she also mentioned in Skanda Purana. See this link:- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52130/is-ashapuri-maa-mentioned-in-any-scripture

Comment: Ok sir, Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

For killing Demon Karnataka, Devi [incarnated](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc423639.html) as Matangi.

> 1-5. Listen, O Skanda of excellent intellect, to a wonderful deed of mine. There was a very wicked Daitya in Dharmāraṇya named Karṇāṭaka. He used to interrupt couples quietly and hinder their activities. All the people were terror-stricken on seeing him. They used to flee. Merchants, religious students and others forsook their abodes. **O son, Śrīmātā assumed the form of a Mātaṅgī (tribal woman, huntress) and killed Karṇāṭaka, a Brāhmaṇa-slayer.** Thereupon, all the Brāhmaṇas were delighted because of that deed. The traders too eulogized and adored Śrīmātā with great devotion. Every year they perform the worship of Śrīmātā.

Devi also [became](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc425590.html) Harasiddhi.

> 8-10. Śiva said, “May those great Daityas be killed.” and she said, “I shall kill them.” Taking up the terrible hammer-like club, she hit furiously. When those Dānavas, arrogant of their prowess, were seen killed by her, Hara told her: “O Caṇḍī, the wicked Dānavas have been killed. Hence you will be well-known in the world by the name Harasiddhi.” **Then onwards that goddess who granted fulfilment to Hara, became famous as Harasiddhi in Mahākāla (vana).**